# Gauge/knob Jquery, Javascript, css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have anyone done this before ? - I'm creating gauge/knob. 
I tried to illustrate idea in this picture
[image]

The idea: you can drag button and according drag button value changes some text and filled color. 
I googled for possible methods - there are several solutions for gauge animation, like gauge.js or http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ but there are none with single drag button for dragging.

Maybe someone has done similar thing before, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i know raphael is bit oversized for quite simple functionality like this but... hope that is going to help You;
http://bseth99.github.io/projects/svg/4-raphael-svg-slider.html
be sure to check circle example